# What defines profile views

Tags: support

I wish I can know how profile views are incrementing.

Is it about Me logging in and out?

Or it's about somebody else visiting my profile?

And if so, assuming that he refreshed the page, does it increase?

Or he will have to logout and login again to let it increase?

And what about some robots doing this anonymously ?

Is there any IP restrictions? (should be visited from multiple IP)

I am sorry if that bothers you. But this question is rolling in my head long time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a hard question.

I found these links in stackoverlow that answers this question.

1. [link 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132688/how-are-profile-views-counted)
2. [link 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter)
3. [link 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138475/idea-behind-profile-view-count)

There no exact answer because the real answer is found with developers of the site. They did not really answer the question because they are so busy. But some friends were trying to answer but analysing the whole process. And I think they are true about what they analised.

Comment: I will accept your answer but I wish that somebody can contact developers and post the real answer